# Why do I have to undeploy and deploy again my webapp in Tomcat at every time I edit its source codes?

Tags: web-applications, web-deployment, tomcat8

I'm using Ubuntu18.04 ,apache2.0 , Tomcat(TomEE)8.5(7.0) and PHP 7.2

I am developing webapp on localhost. At every time I edit and save my app's source codes, I have to undeploy and redeploy my webapp using Tomcat manager app.

How to load the new contents to my webapp as soon as I save edited contents without redeploying it? I meant how to do it with Zero down time.